# How to share matrix in HLSL?

Tags: c++, directx, shaders, hlsl

I am trying to share this across multiple effect files:

```
matrix worldMatrix : register(vs_4_0, b0);
```

1. If I set this from one effect file, will it effect every effect file which has the same type of variable assigned to that specific register?
2. What is the difference between this and the cbuffer struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind a constant to one register, it will be there until something binds at the same place or if you bind that spot with null.

My approach of having constant buffer i want to "share" is to have a constant buffer struct in a include file. and then including that file into all the shaders im using. It's convenient and simple.

The difference with a single value and a cbuffer is how you bind the data and how you have to allocate the buffers. if you have a cbuffer, with 128 floats, you have to create a buffer thats equal of that size. while a single value wont let you create a register spot thats of a difference size than that type. Regularly, it's good to have a cbuffer with specific meanings. In other words, having a cbuffer that gets updated every frame, one that gets updated for each material and maybe one that contains some sort of Per second data.

Comment: Out of curiosity, will the method above by binding a matrix to a single register work in practice? In other words, if I bind a matrix to a single register will it get updated across multiple shader files?

Comment: Maybe, Maybe not. it´s hard to tell when it comes to thees things with out proper code and profiling. ( assuming you are reffering to peformance losses )

Comment: not necessarily performance, just whether it the bonded matrix will be available in all Effect files. I tried binding the matrix to a register and accessing them from a different effect to no avail. That's why I am wondering if this is actually propagating through all effects.

Comment: the register slot have to be the same

Comment: They are and its being set from a different Effect but not working. Does the `set` need to be different? i.e. do I need to specify what  register from c++ code? All I am doing is `ID3D10EffectMatrixVariable#SetMatrix` from one HLSL.

Comment: Oh, you are using the Effect system. You should consider moving to the DX11, and not using the effect system. The effect system will take care of your calls and all the underhood stuff for you. which in optimization point is pretty bad.

Comment: Not using the effect system?

Comment: "Vanila" DX, is used so that you bind constants via buffers, which is created from the gpu memory. and which it later binds to different stages of the the pipeline. so calling a ID3D11Device::PSSetShaderResource or ID3D11Device::PSSetConstantBuffer, would effectivly bind something to that register until unbound. when using the effect system, it will handle that for you and unbind it after each effect file.

Comment: But how do I bind to a particular register? So it stays there during the lifetime of the application or until I change it. In other words, it will be the same in all effect files that are accessing that particular register?

Comment: Also, isn't the constant buffer == VertexType struct?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/fPaotti.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12602/discussion-between-tordin-and-mk1)

Comment: I got one more question for you. I have posted it on the chat.

Comment: I have a quick question for you. How do you resize a `Texture2D`? Do I have to create a new one with the size or is there anyway I can request an update for Texture2D. I am using this Texture2D for caching.

Comment: For texture resizing, i recomend writing a new post about it, itś a entire different topic.